# How to set length of array alias with scoped enum template argument without casting

Tags: c++, templates

My goal is to create an [alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) for a `std::array` that sets the length based on an enum template argument. I managed to make it work relying on the conversion of the enum, as seen in my code below.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

enum class StateRepresentation
{
    Log2 = 1,
    One_hot = 16
};

template <StateRepresentation R>
using State = std::array<int, static_cast<int>(R) * 16>;

int main(void)
{
    const auto curr_repr = StateRepresentation::One_hot;
    auto b = State<curr_repr>{};
    std::cout << "Representation value: " << static_cast<int>(curr_repr) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Array length: " << b.size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Would it be possible to achieve the same but without relying on `static_cast` to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator?

I attempted something along the lines of [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) as seen below, but failed to make it work:

```
template <>
using State<StateRepresentation::Log2> = std::array<int, 1 * 16>;

template <>
using State<StateRepresentation::One_hot> = std::array<int, 16 * 16>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional_t` to switch on which member of the enum class is used for instantiation:

```
template <StateRepresentation R>
using State = std::conditional_t<R == StateRepresentation::Log2,
                                 std::array<int, 1 * 16>,
                                 std::array<int, 16 * 16>>;
```

This avoids the need for the enum class members to have the same *values* as the ones you want to use in the `std::array`.

As pointed out in a comment, you could also use a ternary condition in the array parameter itself to pick the size you want

```
template <StateRepresentation R>
using State = std::array<int, (R == StateRepresentation::Log2 ? 1 : 16) * 16>;
```

Comment: Since only the size is different and not the whole type, you could use `? :`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, that's very nice. I'll add that to the answer, thanks.

Comment: You made me realize that I did not intend to restricted myself to enums with only two members. Luckily, @HolyBlackCat 's idea seems to be expandable to using a lambda with a `switch` in it. (VisualStudio compiled and ran it.)

Comment: @Dudly01 Btw, `? :` can also be used as a poor man's `switch`: `cond1 ? value1 : cond2 ? value2 : cond3 ? value3 : ... : default_value`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Haha, did not see this before. I tried this approach with `std::conditional_t` and works there as well. 
Now I only wonder what would be the proper way to handle when an enum describes both the type and the size.